# ACF and PACF strange behavior

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, modeling, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I have a question on a ACF/PACF result reported below.

Using a daily time series composed by 953 values I have the following result plotting the acf and pacf results.

[image]

My questions are:

1. how can I interpret the fact that in the ACF there are a kind of pick at lag 7, 14, 21 ,ecc ? It seems drop down only at 600th lag
2. how can I interpret the PACF result due to this stange behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would indicate a clear seasonal effect of period 7 (such as you might see with a "day-of-week" type effect and daily data)

The fact that it extends for a long time suggests you might need seasonal differencing.

If you look at the plots for seasonally differenced series you'll probably see indication of a small ARMA model -- perhaps an MA(1), say.